# Why aren't the letters چ‎, گ‎ or پ‎ found in the Qur'an?

Tags: quran, arabic

I am wondering about the following three letters:

- چ‎ – Che
- گ‎ – Gaf
- پ‎ – Pe

These three letters are not in the Qur'an (not even a single time).

Is there any reason behind that?

Comment: Because these letters are not Arabic!

Answer (score 12):

I assume you are from the area around Iran-Pakistan.

Why do I say this in my answer? That's because the answer to your question is simple!:

The three letters that you have presented **do not exist in Arabic**. Those letters exist in languages such as Persian and Urdu, which are written with an expanded version of the Arabic abjad.

I hope that answers your question.

Answer (score 6):

These are Persian letters and don't exist in the Arabic language. The Qur'an is written in Arabic - it doesn't contain these letters.

Note that there are 4, not 3 : ژ (zhe) is another one.

Comment: [Do not use signature, taglines, or greetings.](http://islam.stackexchange.com/help/behavior)

Answer (score 2):

These letters you mention are not in Arabic alphabet.

For example, according to the [Wikipedia article "Che (Persian letter)"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Che_(Persian_letter)):

> چ‎ – Che is an additional letter of the Persian alphabet, used to
> represent [t͡ʃ], and which derives from ǧīm (ج) by the addition of two
> dots. It is found with this value in other Arabic-derived scripts. It
> is used in Persian, Pashto, Kurdish, Azerbaijani, other Iranian
> languages and Urdu, but not in Arabic. However, it might be used in
> Arabic texts to represent other phonemes when writing words with
> sounds not in Arabic letters.

PS: to learn the Arabic alphabet see this link [The Arabic Alphabet - Chart](http://web.stanford.edu/dept/lc/arabic/alphabet/)

Comment: Salaams and welcome to Islam Stack Exchange.  Answers which consist primarily of text copy-pasted from third party sources are discouraged here (see relevant meta discussion here: http://meta.islam.stackexchange.com/q/953/22).  If your answer *does* involves copied text, it *must* be properly cited and quoted.

Answer (score 1):

the three letters you mention are not in Arabic language

PS : Aayah 29 of surah elfath in Quran contains all Arabic letters

Answer (score -1):

Cha , Gaf and Pa are of the Sanskrit language, a fabrication of dark ages since the time of  Plato. It is in denial of truth as a fundamental of being but, based on a medium of existence called Sanity, base word for the Santa, Saint, santan etc. They are not letters but fabrication to promote immorality by faith faith with the help of fabricated sounds to fool humanity in to illegality.

Truth has no value for the followers of  Pharaoh ism, but end justifies the means, as a way of life.  The letter 'cha' was fabricated to be equal to the Latin, Hebrew or Arabic letter 'Sheen', Sha, meaning form, or follow, and made part of languages influenced by the Sanskrit language, such as Indo-European languages, Persian, and Hindi.  As is the case with word Chamber in English or Chi, in Chinese, and the south Eastern countries, and foundation of Hinduism, Buddhism, Judaism and Christianity.

Comment: Letter Pa is a fabrication of dark ages, based on word of Sanskrit language, used to emphasize possession, and the hand punja, in denial of the truth of inability to posses matters by the humanity in totality, but by the the truth, or possession of Allah the Merciful. Letter P is not just a letter but, denial of truth by intent, and used by the languages influenced by the pagan ism, such as the Hinduism, etc.

Comment: I tried to correct the spelling and grammar as much as I could, but the the sentence structure is so disorganized that it is difficult to understand what is being expressed.  One thought, one sentence.  Do not combine multiple thoughts into one sentence.  There is no need and just leads to confusion.  Also, your statements and claims need to be supported by references.

Comment: No need to be angary or  play smart with words or the grimmer, English language it self is a crime against humanity to fool humanity, using Sanskrit as its foundation. Do not ask for a name of a person to substantiate my words, I do not recognize lies or the incompetence of others to substantiate truth.  Seems like you  do not recognize truth on your own abilities but ready to argue to substantiate denial of truth  using lies  of liars and the crooks of dark and recent age.

Answer (score -1):

Again letter Gaf is of the Sanskrit language, a fabrication to promote denial of truth by faith, such as hinduism, based on racism. Every thing desires by the heart and mind is known as Ya, such as Ya Allah, or as mentioned in Holy Quran, Allah the merciful addressed up HIS beloved messenger Nobel, Mohammad pbh, as Ya Mohammad, and ya, being the base word for the English word Yes, to commit from the heart and mind from its root word Ya. For reasons to hide truth from the humanity, sound ya was converted in to Ga, a desire and made base of the fabricated word called God, an adjective, propagated as noun to fool humanity. Gaf is part of the languages influenced by the Paganism, self center ism, denial of Truth by faith, Such as Hinduism, Buddhism, etc.